# How to use dispatcher to show message by bot in requested_slot function of form in Rasa?

Tags: chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I want to show message by bot for that normally we use `dispatcher.utter_message()`, but how can I use in requested_slot function of form?

```
def required_slots(tracker: Tracker) -> List[Text]:
    //some_code
    dispatcher.utter_message("any text")
    //return [requested_slot]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in domain file utter_ask_[slotname]: The bot will prompt this message whenever the requested slot is missing